# Адаптивное изменение длины OptionMenu в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Написал простую программу-генератор паролей на Python с GUI tkinter.
С помощью чек-боксов пользователь выбирает из чего будет сгенерирован пароль: буквы, цифры, символы.
При этом пароль состоит из неповторяющихся значений и генерируется следующим образом:

```
def generate():
    select = ''
    if var_letters.get() == True:
        select += string.ascii_lowercase
    if var_digits.get() == True:
        select += string.digits
    if var_symbols.get() == True:
        select += string.punctuation

    number_of_letters = menu_var.get()
    password = ''.join(random.sample(select, number_of_letters))
```

Длина пароля задаётся через выбор пункта в OptionMenu и ограничена значениями от 6 до 20:

```
menu_var = IntVar()
length_of_password = [i for i in range(1,21)]
menu_var.set(6)
menu = OptionMenu(root, menu_var, *length_of_password)
menu.place(x=300,y=20)
```

Здесь возникает проблема: если я выберу только цифры и длину пароля больше 10, то естественно вылетит ошибка

```
ValueError: sample larger than population
```

т.к. у нас всего 10 цифр. 
Пробовал делать что-то такое

```
if(var_digits.get() == True and var_letters.get() == False and var_symbols.get() == False):
    length_of_password = [i for i in range(6,11)]
else
    length_of_password = [i for i in range(6,21)]
```

Однако такой вариант не работает.

В связи с этим возникает вопрос, можно ли адаптивно изменять количество пунктов в OptionMenu в зависимости от выбора пользователя?

Comment: а на сколько есть смысл создавать вообще пароль с невторяющиемися значениями?

Comment: Тут дело скорее не в смысле. Мне просто интересно узнать, как можно изменять количество пунктов в меню в зависимости от выбора пользователя. И возможно ли вообще так сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно кажется можно сделать проще, но в данном случае можно просто использовать регулярное выражение если пользователь убирает флажок с пункта

```
import tkinter as tk
import string
import secrets
import re


class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.text_generate = ""
        self.edit = tk.Text(self, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.edit.pack()
        self.text_A = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Заглавные буквы', var=1, command=lambda: self.gen(1)).pack()
        self.text_a = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Обычные буквы буквы', command=lambda: self.gen(2)).pack()
        self.text_n = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Цифры', command=lambda: self.gen(3)).pack()

        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        self.var.set(0)
        self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.var, 1)
        self.menu.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Генерация', command=self.generate).pack()

    def gen(self, num):
        if num == 1:
            if string.ascii_uppercase in self.text_generate:
                self.text_generate = re.sub(r"[^a-z0-9]", "",  self.text_generate)
            else:
                self.text_generate += string.ascii_uppercase
        elif num == 2:
            if string.ascii_lowercase in self.text_generate:
                self.text_generate = re.sub(r"[^A-Z0-9]", "",  self.text_generate)
            else:
                self.text_generate += string.ascii_lowercase
        elif num == 3:
            if string.digits in self.text_generate:
                self.text_generate = re.sub(r"[^a-z A-Z]", "",  self.text_generate)
            else:
                self.text_generate += string.digits
        menu = self.menu["menu"]
        menu.delete(0, "end")
        for v in range(1, (len(self.text_generate) + 1)):
            menu.add_command(label=v, command=lambda value=v: self.var.set(value))
        self.var.set(1)

    def generate(self):
        text = list(set(''.join(secrets.choice(self.text_generate) for _ in range(self.var.get()))))
        while len(text) != int(self.var.get()):
            text.append(secrets.choice(self.text_generate))
            text = list(set(text))
        secrets.SystemRandom().shuffle(text)
        self.edit.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.edit.insert(tk.END, "".join(i for i in text) + "\n")
        self.edit.config(state=tk.DISABLED)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]